# access login button in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I am new to UFT. I am trying to automate one administrative page in my application. But after entering username and password, login button is not getting enabled.
But if am trying to replicate it manually, it is working fine.

Here are the couple of lines from script:

`SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe","https://sl007670.dcm.allianz:12100/acce/"`

```
Browser("Administration Console").Page("Administration Console").WebEdit("acce_LoginPane_username").Set "NLGPRBR"
Browser("Administration Console").Page("Administration Console").WebEdit("acce_LoginPane_password").Set "welcome.1"
Browser("Administration Console").Page("Administration Console").WebElement("Log In").click
```

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: Have you tried using `SendKeys` option using `WScript.Shell` object?

Comment: Also double check the object class of login button. It may be `Link` or `WebButton`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, UFT uses **event** replay type. 
Sometimes this happens because what UFT does, doesn't fire the events required by the AUT (application under test) in order to enable other controls like in your scenario. I'd suggest switching replay type to **mouse** and then, set WebEdit values. For example:

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType")=2 'mouse
Browser("Administration Console").Page("Administration Console").WebEdit("acce_LoginPane_username").Set "NLGPRBR"
Browser("Administration Console").Page("Administration Console").WebEdit("acce_LoginPane_password").Set "welcome.1"
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType")=1 'event (original value)

Browser("Administration Console").Page("Administration Console").WebElement("Log In").click
```